# External data (keys) mapping within own database

Tags: mysql, sql, web-services

I am currently working on a project of a new system.
This system will be using several different web-services to produce composite data.

Some data is compound and I use relational SQL tables (server, in particular, is MySQL) to compose data for further usage.

My problem is that I have to implement some data mapping.

Take countries for example.
Within our system countries are keyed (primary key based of CHAR[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871636/external-data-keys-mapping-within-own-database/7871829#7871829) ascii column) on [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).
One web-service provides data in the very same format. While several other have their own, unique, integer type identifiers.

As I am about to implement in-code mapping, I would like to have a possibility to dynamically update mapping tables, without making changes to the code.
Thus I am thinking about mappings table.

I may produce a table `service_mappings`, that would contain arbitrary length columns such as `service_id` (my own identifier for particular service), `ref_id` (datum provided by web-service), `model` (what data I am mapping this to in my system), `key` (what key this [`service_id`, `ref_id`] correspond to in my `model`).

On the other hand, I may choose something like a mapping table for each separate model, that would contain less keys (take `model` from previous table, as it would be defined by table name). This could be more feasible to use with ORMs of some kind.

So, my question is as following: what is the **correct** approach, what is the most **efficient**, and maybe there is some completely different technique?

**Cache hint**
In response to recent [answer by Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871636/external-data-keys-mapping-within-own-database/7871829#7871829).
We are likely to use some caching technique (such as *memcache*), although for primary data source we would like to rely on **MySQL** as we have methods in-place for creating and restoring back-ups, and we would have to think how to implement them.

Also, MySQL seems to inhibit some methods for faster access, and according to [research by DeNA](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html) it may, actually, be faster than noSQL alternatives on primary-key/unique-key look-ups.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, i'm would leave model in mapping table instead create separate tables, because it's will be much easer to find proper mapping. If you want more efficient, you may use some nosql storage for this mapping (such as Redis or memcachedb) , which is often much faster and reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I have made some changes to original question with regard to _caching_.

Comment: ok, if you can overclock mysql it's good, one table has only one big con - locking, escpecially on massive insert. But its can be solved in many ways. Pros and cons of one table depends on real situation and may changed in time, but one table good point to start.

Comment: Well, locking due to massive inserts is not a question in particular, as we are about to perform major data insertions off-line; only _deltas_ will be added later.
I think we will give a try for a single table, thanks for sharing.